# Wrong difference in minutes in Oracle (DATE2-DATE1)*24*60

Tags: oracle, date

I'm trying to calculate difference in minutes between two dates in Oracle with this testing query:

```
SELECT 
  (DATE2-DATE1)*24*60 DIFFINMINUTES
FROM
(
  SELECT
    TO_DATE('2014-06-06 10:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') DATE1,
    TO_DATE('2014-06-06 11:25', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') DATE2
  FROM DUAL
);
```

The expected result should be **55 minutes** but I'm getting **54,99999999**.

ROUNDing this value gets the job done but I really wants to understand why this calculation was this behavior.

Comment: Welcome to the world of computer arithmetics! Rounding errors like this can always occur in the strangest places.

Comment: DATE1 - DATE2 Oracle calculates the difference in days. That's why some inaccuracy may occur.

Comment: Since a date has the date plus time. So, the fraction is due to the time part. The fraction is in days. 0.5 would mean 12 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DATE2 - DATE1` Oracle calculates the difference in days. That's why some inaccuracy may occur.

Just an example with timestamps

```
select inter,
       extract (day from inter) days,
       extract (hour from inter) hours,
       extract (minute from inter) minutes,
       extract (second from inter) seconds
from
(select 
  cast(date2 as timestamp) - cast(date1 as timestamp) inter
FROM
(
  SELECT
    TO_DATE('2014-06-06 10:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') DATE1,
    to_date('2014-06-06 11:25', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') date2
  from dual
));
```

Substraction of timestamps gives you exact INTERVAL